# Django profile update comes out as an error

Tags: python, django

I have been developing a blog and facing the same issue again and again.

""  p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile) ""

This part of the code is showing an error and I have no idea what to do. I have tried everything.

The error is ""Exception Value: User has no profile.""

I tried manually creating a profile. No use. Please help

Comment: What is the model used for your ModelForm? Please show this code and the solution should be simple

Answer (score 1):

> "User has no profile" indicates that the request.user object does not have an associated Profile object. This usually means that the Profile model is related to the User model through a one-to-one relationship, and in your code, the request.user does not have an associated Profile object. To resolve this issue, you need to ensure that a Profile object is associated with each User object.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).